# how can my unittest file know $app/navigation of sveltekit

Tags: unit-testing, svelte, sveltekit

It is my svelte code(in +page.svelte).

```html
import { goto } from "$app/navigation";
```

And i write unittest code like this:

```html
import myTest from "./+page.svelte"
```

but this error.

**Error: Failed to resolve import "$app/navigation" from "src\routes\mariner+page.svelte". Does the file exist?**

How can I edit `vitest.config.js` to import "$app" of sveltekit?

Comment: "mariner+.page.svelte" looks like it's missing a slash, and the slashes are backwards in the error message, what OS, show your myTest code too